# Replacing names starting with underscore

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I'm trying to write a function to replace names starting with underscore with name with dash. replacing the first character if it starts with underscore with dash. I have done the following so far; but I need somehelp to do it recursively for nested objects; I'm looking for an elegant way to do it:

```
    var myObj = { name: 'foo',
      bar: {"_foo": {'_bar':{}}},
      '_baz': {}};


Object.prototype.replaceUnderscores = function rec() {
    for (var item in this){
      if(typeof this[item] == "object"){
        this[item] = rec(this[item])
      }
      if(_.startsWith(item, '_')){
        console.log(item)
        var newName = item.replace(item[0],'-')
        this[newName] = this[item];
        delete this[item]
      }
    }
    return this;
};

myObj.replaceUnderscores()

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: "Elegant" in what way? Call `replaceUnderscores` on item values that are objects ("maps"/"hashes"). That's kind of the definition of recursive. What's the issue?

Comment: Are you dealing with cyclical structures (i.e. `a={}, b={}; a.b = b; b.a = a;`)? Since that would make what you're trying to do much more complicated.

Comment: @tcooc Wouldn't you just need to keep track of the paths to objects you've visited and avoid visiting the same one twice?

Comment: @DaveNewton: yeah, like he said, complicated. (as opposed to just naive looping)

Comment: I just updated my code to do it recursively but it see item as "top" and the loop goes forever!... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @dandavis So we have different ideas about what "much more complicated" means, life goes on.

Comment: @DaveNewton: i think tcooc and I meant relatively, and you're thinking absolutely. Of course it's not rocket science, but it is probably over twice as much code. i doubt we disagree on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some errors trying your code (_ not defined in the startsWith call).  Also don't see the need to name the function since it's assigned as a prototype, but the following works:

```
var myObj = { 
    name: 'foo',
    bar: {
        "_foo": {
            '_bar': {}
        }
    },
    '_baz': {}
};

console.log('before: %o', myObj);

Object.prototype.replaceUnderscores = function() {
    for (var item in this){
      if(typeof this[item] == "object"){
        this[item] = this[item].replaceUnderscores();
      }

      if(item.startsWith('_')){

        var newName = item.replace(item[0],'-');
        console.log(item + ' / ' + newName);
        this[newName] = this[item];
        delete this[item]
      }
    }
    return this;
};

console.log('after: %o', myObj.replaceUnderscores());
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1rsgxfc/1/)

**Update**

I now see the error.  WHere you say

```
this[item] = rec(this[item])
```

I say

```
this[item] = this[item].replaceUnderscores();
```

Even if you name the function you do not pass in the object to be changed as a parameter - it is part of the object prototype and it works on `this`.

Comment: re: "Also don't see the need to name the function since it's assigned as a prototype", it can help debugging and profiling to make sure all functions have names...

Comment: So my mistake was just making anonmous function to a named function? Thats why it was not working?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using a library to get the `_.` stuff to work.  In pure js I got an error on that.  Always worth mentioning in questions.  I think your error is not that you name the function, but that you call it with a parameter - it doesn't take a param, it works on this.  Will update answer

Comment: @dandavis: Yes, you can.  personally I think that it has been named as replaceUnderscore.  In almost nay other situation I agree that annonymous functions can have that problem, but here we are adding it to the prototype.  Giving the same function two names makes the code confusing (e.g. the error the OP had here)

Comment: Totally unrelated, and highly nitpicky, but naming this "replaceUnderscores" seems a bit misleading to me since that's not really precisely what it's doing. Sorry, in code review mode today :(